# What is the use of LinkedHashMap.removeEldestEntry?

Tags: java, collections

I am aware the answer to this question is easily available on the internet. I need to know what happens if I choose not to `removeEldestEntry`. Below is my code:

```
package collection;

import java.util.*;

public class MyLinkedHashMap {

   private static final int MAX_ENTRIES = 2;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      LinkedHashMap lhm = new LinkedHashMap(MAX_ENTRIES, 0.75F, false) {

         protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
            return false;
         }
      };
      lhm.put(0, "H");
      lhm.put(1, "E");
      lhm.put(2, "L");
      lhm.put(3, "L");
      lhm.put(4, "O");

      System.out.println("" + lhm);

   }
}
```

Even though I am not allowing the `removeEldestEntry` my code works fine.
So, internally what is happening?

Comment: What do you actually expect to happen if you disable the method? What do you want it to do? What happens on your end?

Comment: If you choose not to implement it... It won't be implemented. What's the question? Why wouldn't your code shown work without it? You don't remove anything, let alone the oldest entry.

Answer (score 38):

`removeEldestEntry` always gets checked after an element was inserted. For example, if you override the method to always return true, the LinkedHashMap will always be empty, since after every `put` or `putAll` insertion, the eldest element will be removed, no matter what. The JavaDoc shows a very sensible example on how to use it:

```
protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest){
    return size() > MAX_SIZE;
}
```

In an alternative way, you might only want to remove an entry if it is unimportant:

```
protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest){
    if(size() > MAX_ENTRIES){
       if(isImportant(eldest)){
          //Handle an important entry here, like reinserting it to the back of the list
          this.remove(eldest.getKey());
          this.put(eldest.getKey(), eldest.getValue());
          //removeEldestEntry will be called again, now with the next entry
          //so the size should not exceed the MAX_ENTRIES value
          //WARNING: If every element is important, this will loop indefinetly!
       } else {
           return true; //Element is unimportant
       }
    return false; //Size not reached or eldest element was already handled otherwise
}
```

Comment: since after every put or putAll insertion, the eldest element will be removed : BEFORE every put/putall insertion, the eldest element is removed

Answer (score 33):

Why can't people just answer the OP's simple question!

If `removeEldestEntry` returns `false` then no items will ever be removed from the map and it will essentially behave like a normal `Map`.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on [the answer by DavidNewcomb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32349301/3798217):

I'm assuming that you are learning how to implement a cache.

The method `LinkedHashMap.removeEldestEntry` is a method very commonly used in cache data structures, where the size of the cache is limited to a certain threshold. In such cases, the `removeEldestEntry` method can be set to automatically remove the oldest entry when the size exceeds the threshold (defined by the `MAX_ENTRIES` attribute) - as in the example provided [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry(java.util.Map.Entry)).

On the other hand, when you override the `removeEldestEntry` method this way, you are ensuring that *nothing ever happens* when the `MAX_ENTRIES` threshold is exceeded. In other words, the data structure would not behave like a cache, but rather a normal map.

Answer (score 2):

Your `removeEldestEntry` method is identical to the default implementation of `LinkedHashMap.removeEldestEntry`, so your LinkedHashMap will simply behave like a normal LinkedHashMap with no overridden methods, retaining whatever you values and keys put into it unless and until you explicitly remove them by calling remove, removeAll, clear, etc.  The advantage of using LinkedHashMap is that the collection views (`keySet()`, `values()`, `entrySet()`) always return Iterators that traverse the keys and/or values in the order they were added to the Map.