# Removing the least accessed object from a collection

Tags: java, collections

Suppose I have a collections of object, such as flights objects,the list is getting too large and I would like to remove the objects that are the least accessed. How do I know which object are the most accessed? How do I know the object that are the least accessed?
Does any collection in Java provide this information?
Does Java collections place the most recently accessed object in the front?
Suppose I would like to remove the 1/3 of the list.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use LinkedHashMap as such a collection. It usually places the most recently use at the end.

[What is the use of LinkedHashMap.removeEldestEntry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772869/what-is-the-use-of-linkedhashmap-removeeldestentry)

Answer (score 1):

You can use LinkedHashMap. It has special constructor to main least recently accesses.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

> A special constructor is provided to create a linked hash map whose
>   order of iteration is the order in which its entries were last
>   accessed, from least-recently accessed to most-recently
>   (access-order). This kind of map is well-suited to building LRU
>   caches. Invoking the put, putIfAbsent, get, getOrDefault, compute,
>   computeIfAbsent, computeIfPresent, or merge methods results in an
>   access to the corresponding entry (assuming it exists after the
>   invocation completes). The replace methods only result in an access of
>   the entry if the value is replaced. The putAll method generates one
>   entry access for each mapping in the specified map, in the order that
>   key-value mappings are provided by the specified map's entry set
>   iterator. No other methods generate entry accesses. In particular,
>   operations on collection-views do not affect the order of iteration of
>   the backing map.

LinkedHashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, boolean accessOrder)
Constructs an empty LinkedHashMap instance with the specified initial capacity, load factor and ordering mode.